# Possible construction bug in std::poisson_distribution

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

I am not sure this is the right platform for this comment/question, however consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
int main()
{
    int m=std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    std::cout<<m<<"\n";
    std::poisson_distribution<int> p(m+1.);//implicit conversion to double
    std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());
    auto x=p(rng);
    std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs. Though clearly it is not sampling correctly the distribution since 50% of the times x should be larger that m+1, something not allowed. On my machine the program spits out only numbers smaller than m but this may be a sort of undefined behavior. In fact if I print `std::cout<<p.max()<<"\n";` I obtain m.
Now, I know that mathematically speaking I am essentially sampling from a normal distribution and I could easily go around the issue. However I am wondering if a
a run-time exception should be thrown when the distribution is constructed or if a note should be added in the following page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/poisson_distribution.
In the case you agree with me who should I contact?

Comment: Output `p.min()` and `p.max()` - now looking for a reference to explain this

Comment: p.min()=0 and p.max()=std::numeric_limits<int>::max(). But it may be my machine with my compiler.

Comment: So you are generating a random set of `int` numbers distributed around `MAXINT + 1`?

Comment: Yes. But this was just an example made for sake of clarity. You would still sample the distribution incorrectly if the probability of extracting a number larger than MAXINT is non-negligible.

Comment: I think any requirements would be here [rand.req.dist](https://eel.is/c++draft/rand.req.dist) but I can't see one.  I think you need to add the [language-lawyer] tag.  I feel this is going to be a case of - garbage-in, garbage-out; with no requirement in the Standard to test for out of range parameters with respect to the result type of the distribution.

Comment: *On my machine the program spits out only numbers smaller than m*  -- that will be true on EVERY machine.  `p` returns `int`, and by definition the values are positive.  It cannot return anything larger than `m`.

Comment: @RichardCritten I added the tag, and I agree with you on the outcome. Though I think that a note on the web-page should be added.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am not sure, on some machines you may get negative integers or everything else since signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: But this isn't a case of signed integer overflow.  The mathematics are all hidden inside the class, and the class is specified to return "non-negative integer values".

Comment: @alessiolapolla internally it may be using floating point (or what ever it likes) and if too large clamping the output value to the max possible for the return type.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  cppreference.com just documents the standard.  They don't interpret the standard.  You're asking for pathological behavior here.  I'm not sure it's up to the standard to caution against that.

Comment: I see the idea - the code, does not match word for word the specification, the distribution does not match. Maybe it should be specified, maybe it's obvious. I can't find anything that would make it specified in https://eel.is/c++draft/rand. Gcc just takes the next number until it's in range [gcc random.tcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/random.tcc#L1390) . Llvm seems to just "clamp to integral" the return value [llcm poisson_distribution.h](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__random/poisson_distribution.h#L241).

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. As far as I can tell, the behavior you're seeing is not in violation fo the standard. StackOverflow is not a forum for discussion on how the C++ should be changed or whether notes should be added to cppreference (which is a wiki anyways). I'm voting to close.

Comment: @idmean He seems to be asking whether the standard says what to do when the probabilities would create numbers that cannot fit into the specified type.

Answer (score 2):

*All* Poisson distributions have support over all non-negative integers.  As such, there are **always** values that are not generated because they are too large.  One could argue either that such values should be clamped to the range or that they be redrawn.  For reasonable values of *λ*, neither has any practical effect, but picking an unusual parameter will force the inevitable choice to be a dominant effect.

Comment: The standard already covers this: "The value of each probability density function p and of each discrete probability function P specified in this subclause **is 0 everywhere outside its stated domain**." Values that are not representable are never generated.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That doesn’t say what happens to the rest of the function, though, to keep its integral 1.