# Why does std::poisson_distribution hang when passed a very large mean?

Tags: c++, stl, std, libstdc++

For example, the following code hangs, using my setup with a recent version of g++ and GNU libraries:

```
#include <random>
#include <cstdio>

std::default_random_engine rng;

int main(){
    std::poisson_distribution<long> mine(34387423874230847234.0);
    std::printf("%ld\n", mine(rng));
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RY3RCoMgFIav51NIY1CwjSihqOhJBtLU5IAdQ@1q7NmdTMZuzg8/3/cfse83LUSMZ0BhDqno5BaUdpvJvxE@SLAzISmHQap1OUzgmeMKNaCiDvVICGCg2wJYVi9y@tK7Be8tcgk@OHgeASxOxqKe6Za8smVt37Emn7pnXdOye12NP92lybUsLkY@sLhmJ/2qEvGO8QM)

The description for the min and max functions [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/poisson_distribution/) seems to suggest that it will clamp the output to the maximum possible value of the type parameter, in this case `long`. But clearly that's not happening. Is this expected behavior?

Edit: When I link against LLVM libc++, the poisson distribution always returns `LLONG_MAX`, which is more what I'd expect. Is this a GNU libstdc++ bug?

Comment: Use `std::cout`, not `printf`.  You are risking undefined behavior by using the wrong output format specifier.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've updated my code. The code I adapted this from didn't even print out the random number, so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We [just discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397376/possible-construction-bug-in-stdpoisson-distribution#comment124441622_70397376) that libstdc++ **normalizes** the part of the probability distribution that fits in the output type (so the *relative* probabilities are correct) whereas libc++ **clamps** it (so that the *mean* is as correct as possible).  The former approach has greatly increased expected runtime in the case where the parameter is uselessly large, but I would hesitate to call that a bug.

The `min` and `max` member functions describe what can happen, and are accurate: they do not imply either mechanism for making that happen.

Comment: And to clarify for future readers: GNU libstdc++ keeps sampling from the distribution until it's in the range, while libc++ samples once at full (double?) range, then clamps it into range.